# VirtualBox will not boot OS X optical drive

Tags: macos, mac, boot, virtualbox, virtual-machine

**Problem**:

*How to create have a new VirtualBox VM boot the Mac OS X disc image.*

I have a Mac Mini running OS X Yosemite (10.10.4) onto which I installed the latest VirtualBox (5.0.0.0.r101573). I downloaded OS X El Capital beta from the Apple developer portal/store.

**Steps**:

1. Extracted InstallESD.dmg and placed a copy in my Downloads folder. One can get the disc image by selecting "Show Package Contents" in the context menu and going to the "/Contents/SharedSupport" folder.
2. Started the Mac VM, OS boots to UEFI shell.
3. Mounted the disc image as an optical drive. Note: Optical drive is first in the boot order.
4. Type **reset** in the shell to reboot the OS.

I keep receiving the UEFI Shell prompt. Nothing that I do can get me to get the VM to boot the disk image.

I tried creating a physical DVD, but that landed in failure, and I do not think that would make a difference. (I think that I need Verbatim DVD+R DL discs compared to the TDK DVD+R DL that I have now based on my Google search. Macs are picky.)

I created a bootable OS X USB drive, but that did not fair too well, as Oracle does not support bootable USB sticks.

I have tried many things, just nothing successful.

How do I get the the VM to recognize the InstallESD.dmg boot media and boot to that?

Yes, I am aware of the hardware requirements. I read the manual. I have 1 CPU, 1GB RAM, the PIIX3 chipset, and other default settings based on Mac OS X (64-bit).

Comment: I don't believe it's as simple as extracting the InstallESD.dmg image.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/307103/6943

Comment: And then there is this.  The whole process is quite involved...  https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=85631